# What are Internet of Things specific-parameters (network metrics) to focus on when writing a program

Tags: python, networkx, iot

I am trying to model an IoT Network by using the library "NetworkX" by creating a graph, but I don't know what are the parameters and network metrics that I should measure through my program.

I want to cover as much details as I can in my python program (about nodes, flows or any thing else) and by the end, I measure the performance of this network

Until now, I work on these:

- Total number of nodes within the IoT network,
- The latency time (the amount of time it takes to receive a DATA / answer).

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: seems like a pretty open ended question; not sure how suitable it is for stack overflow.  that said; how about network topology and device availability

Comment: Well, I should start with sample stuff then I increase the complexity progressively. As you said, the availability of a device is an important thing and should be taken into consideration (depending on the type of this device) but it stills much more. I start exploring the "NetworkX" library and I need someone who had experience with just to know how much it can be useful in this work ? and How ?